# Why do IQ Impairements, Quadrature Skew and DC offset have these geometric effects on the constellation?

Tags: modulation, software-defined-radio, radio, digital-to-analog

I'm studying telecommunications, and would like to be sure to understand the maths behind these effects.

For IQ Imbalance and DC offset, it seems pretty clear why we observe a rectangle shape or a translation of the constellation, but for the quadrature skew, I don't see why we she this parallelogram shape, that stretch more when the skew is growing.

Could you please, neither with maths or graph explain this behavior ?

Thanks for your help !

[image: Modulation problems graphs generated with LabVIEW]

Comment: I think the name "phase imbalance" is more common than "quadrature skew" (unless I'm mistaking the effect). I recommend "Digital Signal Processing in Modern Communications Systems" by A. Schwarzinger, chapter 5. It is inexpensive and has the best review of impairments I've seen.

Comment: Yes, what I'm calling "Quadrature Skew" is the fact that the I and Q signal are not perfectly in quadrature (i.e phase difference of 90°), then Phase Imbalance seems to describe the same problem. I will check with this keyword if I can find more information on it.

Answer (score 0):

The points are being mapped from a circle (90 deg) to an ellipse (< 90 deg) to a line (0 deg). This is because the complex nature of the number is not as "complex" as expected as the weight on the one of the quantities part is fading given that there is "more" skew.